# Understanding convergence of sequences in metric spaces

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces, definition, intuition

Rudin told me that a sequence $\{p_n\}$ converges  to $p$ in a metric space $X$, if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$n \geq N \implies d(p,p_n) < \epsilon$$

I don't understand how this corresponds to my naive "sloppy-calculus" understanding of converging sequences in $\mathbb{R}$; which if they converge, they get closer and closer to $p$ and "reaching it at infinity".

In particular I don't understand how the existence of $N$ such that $n \geq N$ could imply that the distance between $p$ and $p_n$ is less than  $\epsilon$. I can't really wrap my head around this concept in the rigorous formulation.

Can someone explain how one should think about this, perhaps together with a simple example or two?

I hope this question isn't too fuzzy, I'm taking a course in real analysis and to be honest I'm really struggling with understanding the material.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is a desired approximation, say $0.1$, $0.01$, $0.0001$..., and can be as close to $0$ as you want. The definition say that if a sequence converge to $p$ then you can choose **any** desired approximation $\epsilon$, say $0.0001$, and all elements of the sequence starting from a some number $N$ (say $1000$) will give you approximation better than $\epsilon$.

Comment: However small distance $\epsilon$ you specify, you can divide the sequence into two parts: first part has finitely many elements and the second part has infinitely many, all of which are at most $\epsilon$ distance away from the limit. No matter how small bubble you put around the limit point, there's an index, after which all the elements of the sequence are in the bubble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the statement says is:
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0,\ \exists N_\varepsilon\text{ s.t. } \forall n\geq N_\varepsilon, \text{ we have } d(p_n,p) < \varepsilon
$$
Let us break it down:

- > $\forall \varepsilon > 0$:

no matter how close you want it to be

- > $\exists N_\varepsilon$

there exists an index of the sequence (which can depend on the "how close you want" parameter $\varepsilon$)

- > such that $\forall n\geq N_\varepsilon$

such that after this index, the terms of the sequence

- > $d(p_n,p) < \varepsilon$

stay as close as you wanted from the limit.

The use of that index $N_\varepsilon$ is to say that sure, the first few terms of the sequence (the first 10, 45, or maybe $10^6/\varepsilon$) can be as far as $p$ as they want; but *after that*, they **have** to remain very close to the limit $p$. I.e., this definition captures the following intuitive idea:

> "if you are a sequence that converges to $p$, then after a while your terms all better be close to $p$."